# df generates duplicate entries

Tags: command-line, df

`df` command generates duplicate entries, like so:

```
mr@ubx:~$ df /*
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/sda2                    473M  127M  322M  29% /boot
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
udev                         7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/sda2                    473M  127M  322M  29% /boot
/dev/sda2                    473M  127M  322M  29% /boot
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
proc                            0     0     0    - /proc
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
tmpfs                        1.6G  9.4M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
sysfs                           0     0     0    - /sys
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  213G   65G  137G  33% /
/dev/sda2                    473M  127M  322M  29% /boot
```

Does anybody know what this is caused by?  Is it a problem beyond being confusing to read?

I read a discussion about this issue in the context of Fedora, but I'm not sure they have fixed it.  And I have found nothing about this in the context of Ubuntu.

I'm running 16.04.  I have an encrypted hard disk and an encrypted home folder.

---

fstab looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=4206e141-5643-4f97-8938-944ea4cbd910 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E0AD-85F8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Comment: What does your `/ertc/fstab` file contain?

Comment: fstab  looks like this:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing `df /*`. Note the `/*` - that means every file and directory in the top level of `/` (nitpicks aside). So, in effect:

```
df /bin /boot /etc ...
```

And `df` for a given directory, prints the details of the filesystem on which that directory is, so you get multiple entries.

Just do:

```
df
```